# Inserting single column figure in a two column document without interfere the flow of text

Tags: floats

I am using revtex class with twocolumn option. I insert a figure which spreads to second column. After the placement of that figure, the text shifted to second column instead of continue in the first column. After filling up the empty space in the second column above the figure, the text start from the first column. Please help me.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prl,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4}
\textheight 750pt
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{caption2}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\thefigure}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\newcommand{\D}{\textrm{d}}
\newcommand{\sech}{\textrm{sech}}

\begin{document}

    While trying to learn the American manual alphabet I discovered a   computer method to read text as if it were being finger spelled. All one needs is a Windows word-processor (or something equivalent) and a sign-language font.

I'm quite happy with the result and think it will interest any persons who are learning the American manual alphabet themselves. The method should also work for other manual alphabets (such as the two-handed alphabet used in the UK) should fonts ever be made for them. 

\onecolumngrid

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=2in]{T20}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=2in]{T40}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=2in]{T60}
        % \caption{}\label{subfig-2:flate}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{T20C}
        %\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{T40C}
        % \caption{}\label{subfig-2:flate}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{T60C}
        %\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Variation}\label{width_3}
\end{figure}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make it easier for people to help you! Your example can not be run due to the missing figures and it ends with the error message from `\end{eqnarray}`  You can use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so the external figures are not needed.

Comment: You have used `\onecolumngrid` which is a version of `\onecolumn` and like that command forces a page break It is hard to imagine how to switch between one and two columns without forcing a break? perhaps you did not intend to change the main text and just the figure in which case you need `\begin{figure*}`

Answer (score 3):

The question is not too clear but I thionk ypu don't want to force a page break, so don't use

```
\onecolumngrid
```

and use `figure*` to get a two-column figure.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prl,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4}
\textheight 750pt
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%No!!! \usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{caption2}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\thefigure}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\newcommand{\D}{\textrm{d}}% should be \mathrm{d}
\newcommand{\sech}{\textrm{sech}}% I suspect this should be \DeclareMathOperator\sech{sech}

\begin{document}

    While trying to learn the American manual alphabet I discovered a   computer method to read text as if it were being finger spelled. All one needs is a Windows word-processor (or something equivalent) and a sign-language font.

I'm quite happy with the result and think it will interest any persons who are learning the American manual alphabet themselves. The method should also work for other manual alphabets (such as the two-handed alphabet used in the UK) should fonts ever be made for them. 

%\onecolumngrid

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=2in]{T20}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=2in]{T40}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=2in]{T60}
        % \caption{}\label{subfig-2:flate}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{T20C}
        %\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{T40C}
        % \caption{}\label{subfig-2:flate}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2in]{T60C}
        %\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Variation}\label{width_3}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```